# java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/file.txt" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Tags: file, inputstream, filestream

i have this code :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Public Key to encrypt with: ");
String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFilename);
```

when i enter the destination of the file "C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/file.txt", the result is this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/file.txt" (The
>   filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

but the file exist, so what can i do?

Thank u..

Comment: First you have to be 100% sure about the path and the file existence (also for the extension), then try with this: `C:\\Users\\Joe\\Desktop\\file.txt`

Comment: Every one who tells you to use back slashes is wrong. I just tested your code and it works. It means your file.txt is really not there

Answer (score 2):

> when i enter the destination of the file
>   "C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/file.txt"

Filename should be provided without quotes ("")

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I noticed that you were using forward slashes in your filename. If you're on windows, you want to use a backslash ()

If you're 100% sure that this file exists in the specific location, then it is one of two things. Also, try escaping the `/`s in your filename

Java will throw this exception when it is not handled correctly. Surround your statement in a `try ... catch()` block, or put `throws FileNotFoundException`, after having imported `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, like this:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
try{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Public Key to encrypt with: ");
    String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFilename);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File does not exist");
}
```

or

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
void encrypt throws FileNotFoundException(){
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Public Key to encrypt with: ");
    String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFilename);

}
```

Also, another reason is that the file is protected. Set the file to readonly, or read and write if you want to be able to do both.

Comment: note that i'm entering the destination with ""... when i entering the destination without "" another error appears: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: Detect premature EOF

Comment: For that, I think you need to download the [Java Cryptography Extension](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Public Key to encrypt with: ");
String publicKeyFilename = in.readLine();
try
    { 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFilename); 
    } 
catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File error !!!"); 
    }
```